# Changing values in a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a list of tuples:

```
tup = [('a', '10', 0xA), ('b', '9', 0x9)]
```

I am trying to change the values of the 3rd element in it

My attempt:

```
for i, elements in enumerate(tup):
    elements = list(elements)
    elements[2] = 0x99
```

When I check the contents of the tuple, it does not update with new my value.

Input:    `[i for i in tup]`
Output:    `[('a', '10', 10), ('b', '9', 9)]`

Clearly a significant misunderstanding of how these data structures work on my part.

Any help appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: tuples are readonly.

Comment: convert to list make change then convert back to tuple

Comment: I know tuples are immutable(!), but I access them by temporarily changing them to a list....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it to a list and update the values. And the you can change it back to tuple.

**Ex:**

```
tup = [('a', '10', 0xA), ('b', '9', 0x9)]
res = []
for i in tup:
    val = list(i)
    val[-1] = 0x99
    res.append(tuple(val))

print(res)
```

Answer (score -1):

That is not possible:

```
>>> t = (1,2,3)
>>> t[0]
1
>>> t[0] = 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    t[0] = 4
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```